# getExternalFilesDir() returns null (not a permissions issue)

Tags: android

I've been working on an app for some time, and have been testing it on many devices. Suddenly, it stopped working on the Motorola Xoom Family Edition (Honeycomb 3.1). Every time I would try to run the app, it would fail on the call to getExternalFilesDir(), as that call would return null instead of a File.

From my research, anyone with a similar problem is either missing the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, never got an answer, or was talking about a bug in Froyo. None of that applies here--and again, it works fine on other devices, I have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, and it was even working on this device until a few minutes ago.

Any idea what might cause this issue, or how to programmatically prevent it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem went away after I restarted the tablet. It may just be some bizarre quirk that is extremely rare and fixed by a simple restart; I hope not, as I would like to have a solid way to prevent this instead of just hoping that any users who run into the bug are understanding.

Comment: Worked for me. Nothing worse than heisenbug in an OS.

Comment: I will note that the Motorola Xoom Family Edition, from other testing and development I've done, has a lot of bugs and is pretty poorly built software-wise. The other, more popular Xooms are fine. Hopefully the Q4 2012 Ice Cream Sandwich update will help.

Comment: I was affected by the same issue on Nexus 7 device. Restart helped, but this issue is strange.

Comment: Same on a Nexus 5, really disturbing knowing that it is quite a critical method...

Answer (score 7):

Same problem on Samsung SCH-1405 (VZW Galaxy II) running 2.3.6 (kernel 2.6.35.7-FF1). No problems getting the external files directory for months and then bam, it starts to return NULL. Restarted phone and problem went away. Not a good omen.

A possible cause could be that I've been switching this phone in and out of USB debugging mode to get screen shots and have been ripping out the USB cable from the phone without first unmounting the phone's file systems from my Mac. This is new behavior on my part.

When I look at the return result from android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState() with the problem present I see "shared", but when the phone is restarted the result is "mounted". Thus it seems that when the phone thinks that the external storage is "shared" then it is not allowing an app to access the external storage. This is speculation.

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if the device is in "Mass Storage" mode. If you change it to MTP or "Charge Only", depending on the device, it should work. This is because the external data storage is technically not mounted to the device but to your computer.