# getExternalFilesDir(null) returns null for some users

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

So the problem I have is the following,

the following line of code throws a NullPointerException for some users of my app, yet i don`t know why

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state))
    baseDir = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
else
    baseDir = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
```

to be more specific its this part

```
baseDir = getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
```

This code is called in the OnPostCreate() and I also have the required permissions in case you wondered.

So getExternalFilesDir(null) returns null for some reason even though it would be mounted.

I also searched a bit on SO and found related post with the same question but no real answer only good one is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10114801/getexternalfilesdir-returns-null-not-a-permissions-issue) one.

So is this just a problem on some user phones or a problem in general on androids end ?

Answer (score 6):

This is strange. The android documentation says it only returns null when the external storage is not mounted. I think the right thing to is this:

```
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    File baseDirFile = getExternalFilesDir(null);
    if(baseDirFile == null) {
        baseDir = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    } else {
        baseDir = baseDirFile.getAbsolutePath();
    }
} else {
    baseDir = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Comment: hmmm, yeah it pretty much the only solution to this I assume. Yet it  would be interessting to know why this can happen. My only assumption would be that it depends on the implementation of the manufacture.

Comment: I've seen this problem as well, but for me, it's sporadic and does not depend on the user. I think it's a timing problem within the OS, but I haven't been able to make it happen, so I can't submit a bug report.